# Using Hanekeswift with UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift

I had this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("id") as! String


    let url = NSURL (string: "http://visia-ontwikkeling.nl/polen/city_details.php?id=\(id)");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    subtitleLabel.loadRequest(requestObj);
}
```

And I want it to be cached so I can use it without internet but I couldn't find how to do this with HanekeSwift. This is what I tried:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("id") as! String


    let cache = Shared.JSONCache
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://visia-ontwikkeling.nl/polen/city_details.php?id=\(id)");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);

    cache.fetch(URL: url!).onSuccess { JSON in
        self.subtitleLabel.loadRequest(requestObj);
    }
}
```

But it gives me this error in the console:

> 2015-09-15 15:02:38.584 Ontdek Polen[4478:1133249] [HANEKE][ERROR]
>   Invalid JSON data with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
>   "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text
>   did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not
>   set.) UserInfo=0x7fb161454330 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not
>   start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

I know the problem is that it's expecting JSON but I need to load the content of a page instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in using JSONCache when you cannot parse the coming data as JSON. Try, instead, a different Haneke cache type.

In this case, I think you should work with raw data, which would change this line:

```
let cache = Shared.JSONCache
```

into

```
let cache = Shared.dataCache
```